# How to fill form field from URL?

Tags: html, forms

Is there a way to drop in a form value on a webpage that I do not own?

For example:

```
somesite.com/form.html?field1=somevalue
```

Where the `input` field ID is `somevalue`.

I've tried the above via a URL and the field does not populate. If that technique isn't possible, is there some other way to do it?

Comment: If it's a POST form, you may need to use AJAX, but you may run into CORS. Is this a POST form?

Comment: If you mean: method=post, then yes.

Comment: I see. That's not possible with URL parameters, as those are passed as GET. You'll need to use something like AJAX, and that's assuming the site you're hitting consents and allows Cross-Orgin requests (an HTTP header that tells the browser if other websites are allowed to get data from it)

Comment: You could try to proxy it thru PHP on server side, or ask the other owner to enable CORS